# How much does Azure Insights cost if the data retention period exceeds 90 days?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

It is said that data is kept for 90 days for the cost of Azure insights, but if you set a value larger than 90 days, how much will the cost be?

Since the free period is 90 days, will it cost only the amount exceeding that number of days, or will it cost all the number of days if it exceeds?
For example, in the following cases, which is pattern 1 or pattern 2?

When the amount of data is 5 [GB] and the number of data retention days is 120 days,
Pattern 1: 16.80 x 5 x 1 month
Pattern 2: 16.80 x 5 x 4 months

I didn't find the answer when I searched.
I would appreciate if you could let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You only pay the extra part.

This is an example for log analytics, but it works the same way for app insights: https://azure.com/e/891538a848fb4c89ba4876ece4bf7919

You can also check: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/monitor/

> Every GB of data ingested into your Azure Monitor Log Analytics
>   workspace can be retained at no charge for up to the first 31 days.
>   Data retained ***beyond*** the first 31 days will be charged as per the data
>   retention prices listed below.

[image]
That is what it cost to have 1Gb for 121 days (31 free + 90 payed)

Comment: Thank you for teaching me.
I have an additional question,
Since the data of Azure Insights is stored in Log Analytics, does it mean that Log Analytics calculated the value in the retention period?

Comment: The prices change per region, I believe it is the same as log analytics. But you can check this to be sure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/monitor/  (In there search for `Data Retention` in `Application Insights`).

Comment: ``Every GB of data ingested by Application Insights is retained at no charge for 90 days.[this site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/monitor/)  ''
It was written.Is it something other than 90 days worth of calculations?

Comment: If you use app insights, you have free retention for 90 days. You pay for every extra day after the 90, The cost per extra day is equal to Log Analytics extra day cost. On top of that you would pay if you use the other app insight features, like load tests, etc.